# Rxjs Scheduler: What's the difference between asap and async?

Tags: rxjs

Could somebody tell me the difference between Scheduler.asap and Scheduler.async?

Looks the same for me:

```
const observable = Observable.create(function (observer) {
  observer.next(1);
  observer.next(2);
  observer.next(3);
  observer.complete();
})
.observeOn(asap);
//.observeOn(async);

console.log('just before subscribe');
observable.subscribe({
  next: x => console.log('got value ' + x),
  complete: () => console.log('done'),
});
console.log('just after subscribe');
```

Returns:

```
just before subscribe
just after subscribe
got value 1
got value 2
got value 3
done
```

Code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-85vczc?file=app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Have you read a documentation? There is a table which describes their differences - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/scheduler.md#scheduler-types

Answer (score 3):

From: Randall Koutnik Book “Build Reactive Websites with RxJS.” :

**RxJS** has **two** different types of **asynchronous schedulers**: **asap** and **async**.  The key difference is that **asap** schedules the **observable event** to be run using the **micro task queue (process.nextTick() in Node.js, or setTimeout in the browser).**  This means that the event runs **after** any **synchronous code** but **before** any other scheduled **asynchronous tasks**.  The other major scheduler, **async**, schedules using **setTimeout**, and is appropriate for **some time-based operations**.

Answer (score 0):

The `async` scheduler is best used for time-based operations (uses `setInterval` even if time delay is 0... ex. polling), where the `asap` scheduler is better for asynchronous operations that need to happen as quickly as possible irregardless of time.

See more [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/scheduler.md#scheduler-types).

Answer (score 0):

The Aysnc scheduler to be considered as you wrap in a setTimeout or setInterval(Event loop macro task)

The Asap scheduler to be considered as you wrap in a Promise (Micro task executed next after the current Macro task)